# How to get unique records with month and year from timestamp with timestamp sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

```
Select Date_format(effective_date, "%M %Y") as time 
from articles 
order by effective_date desc limit 10;
```

```
+----------------+                                                 
| time           |                                  
+----------------+                                  
| November 2019  |                                  
| November 2019  |                                  
| September 2019 |                                  
| September 2019 |                                  
| August 2019    |                                  
| July 2019      |                                  
| June 2019      |                                  
| May 2019       |                                  
| April 2019     |                                  
| March 2019     |                                  
+----------------+
```

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_page_details_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `effective_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_admin_user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by_admin_user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_articles_on_author_id` (`author_id`),
  KEY `index_articles_on_created_by_admin_user_id` (`created_by_admin_user_id`),
  KEY `index_articles_on_updated_by_admin_user_id` (`updated_by_admin_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to fetch unique records only.
**distinct** is not working and if I use **group by** then order isn't working.

mysql version is 8.0

with **Distinct** I'm getting the error.

```
Select distinct(Date_format(effective_date, "%M %Y")) as time 
from articles 
order by effective_date desc limit 10;
```

> ERROR 3065 (HY000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT
>   list, references column 'articles.effective_date' which is not in
>   SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

Comment: `DISTINCT` will remove duplicates, what to you mean by *is not working*?

Comment: post the complete table data and a `SHOW CREATE TABLE articles ` ... i assume that `effective_date` isn't the only column.. The main problem here seams is that the sort on strings can have unpredicable results because of charset/collation rules

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` is not a function. No need to use parentheses with it..

Comment: Use this **Select distinct Date_format(effective_date, '%M %Y')**

Comment: @PKP order is incorrect with your query

Comment: @RaymondNijland wont work. April come before January because order by is on a string now.

Comment: i think i need more coffee for sure.. @MadhurBhaiya i just said it meself.. *"The main problem here seams is that the sort on strings can have unpredicable results because of charset/collation rules –"*

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's not working as it sorts all month names without respect of year and date

Comment: using a window function (`ROW_NUMBER()`) and using a subquery to filter and sort on the row_number column also might be a option here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses `GROUP BY`:

```
select date_format(effective_date, '%Y %M') new_effective_date
from articles
group by year(effective_date), month(effective_date),  date_format(effective_date, '%Y %M')
order by year(effective_date) desc, month(effective_date) desc
limit 10
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hJyvawG5o6cUzrHjf8Z3yF/2)**:

```
with articles as (
      select '2018-01-01' effective_date
      union all select '2018-01-01' 
      union all select '2018-02-01' 
      union all select '2018-03-01' 
 )
select date_format(effective_date, '%Y %M') new_effective_date
from articles
group by year(effective_date), month(effective_date), date_format(effective_date, '%Y %M')
order by year(effective_date) desc, month(effective_date) desc
limit 10;

| new_effective_date |
| ------------------ |
| 2018 March         |
| 2018 February      |
| 2018 January       |
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `DISTINCT` clause with `ORDER BY`, you need to ensure that the fields used for `ORDER BY` should be selected in the `SELECT` clause as well.

Now, you are converting a datetime value `(Y-m-d h:i:s)` format to `(M Y)`, and using it to sort. But it will not give you correct results, because `2019-01-01 < 2019-04-01`, but when converted to your custom string format, it would give `January 2019 < April 2019`, because `A` is smaller than `J` in char comparisons.

So, one convoluted way could be to reconvert your custom "Month Year" string back to date format `(Y-m-d)` using [`Str_To_Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function for proper sorting:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table articles (`effective_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL);

insert into articles values ('2019-01-05');
insert into articles values ('2019-01-06');
insert into articles values ('2019-02-05');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date_format(effective_date, "%M %Y") as time_MY 
FROM articles 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(time_MY, ' 1'), '%M %Y %d') desc 
limit 10;
```

**Result**

```
| time_MY       |
| ------------- |
| February 2019 |
| January 2019  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFub7CREjFSdxMv34mVBGq/0)

Comment: It's working. Thanks!
Could you please explain this query?

Answer (score 0):

You may get help with this

```
 Select distinct Date_format(effective_date, "%M %Y") as time 
    from articles 
    order by effective_date desc limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `group by`, with an `order by` like this:

```
select Date_format(effective_date, '%M %Y') as time 
from articles 
group by time
order by min(effective_date) desc
limit 10;
```

This allows you to:

- select only one column
- have unique values
- order by the actual date and not the string form